# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'simplecolorpicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code in colorselect.js:

```
$('select[name="colorpaper"]').simplecolorpicker();
```

But the error that comes out `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'simplecolorpicker' in my JS console.`

The jquery plugin in question is already loaded before colorselect.js is loaded but it gives me this error saying it doesn't know the method, which i get confused with why it has the error.

my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery.simplecolorpicker.js
//= require_tree
```

Comment: If you are getting that error, it is in fact not loaded as a plugin of `$`. Make sure your scripts are in the correct order. (jQuery first)

Comment: I have included my application.js for your review.

Comment: I'm not familiar with whatever that is (rails?) all i know is the plugin isn't included properly in some way. That's the only way you can get said error.

Comment: Open the network tab of your browser console and reload the page. Look for any requests for scripts that fail. You could also view the source of the page and look for script references that are incorrect.

Comment: The scripts load well. 304 - not modified. I have checked if there are any duplicate jquery and jquery-ui scripts and removed them (they're excess stuff) but the error still never goes away.

Comment: view the page source. Where is your script in relation to jQuery and the plugin? in the head? in the body? before it? after it?

Comment: What kind of code is that? It's just a bunch of comments.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax, but I see a discrepancy... you have `require jquery`, and `require jquery.simplecolorpicker.js`. Should it instead be `require jquery.simplecolorpicker` (without the `.js`)?

Comment: I am following: https://github.com/tkrotoff/jquery-simplecolorpicker-rails - i have done what it had mentioned and from the JS console, i saw it loading once only.

Comment: The error is gone after deleting the unnecessary jquery files and even so, everything loads OK but the page doesn't render with the palette like it should.